# How can I clear the swift warning "will never be excuted"?

Tags: swift

Now I am learning the swift and when I use the if - else ,the Xcode shows me a warniing "will not be excuted".Though it isn't a big problem, I don't want to see this, how can I clear this warning in the project?

Comment: Could you paste some code so that we can help you?

Answer (score 2):

This is from a logic error that the compiler has picked up and is warning you about.

It gives the line number in your code that can never be reached.

a) Change the logic of your code

b) delete or comment out lines of code that can never be reached

The compiler will not give this message unnecessarily

example

```
if 1 == 2 {
  a = 3
}

else {
  a = 4
}
```

Obviously the condition is never met, the a=3 assignment can never happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = 3;
let b = 4;

if (a == 3) {
    print("executed")
} else if (a == 5) {
    print("never be executed")
} else {
    print("not executed")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's LLVM compiler is pretty verbose when it tells you about warnings - if you check the logs you would find something like:
`warning: will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]`

So to suppres that warning, you need to set the flag `-Wno-unreachable-code`. This works for the ObjC compiler, but currently isn't supported by the Swift compiler

Comment: This answer leaves the code and error in your program. The line of code is never reached and remains as unnecessary. This adds a maintenance burden on future programmers that need to modify or correct your code. I would not allow this solution in my shop, it would be rejected by a decent code review and never get into production.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The Swift compiler does not currently support `-Wno-unreachable-code`, or any other flag-based warning deactivation.

Comment: I definitely agree that such warnings shouldn't be suppressed, but if you really wanted to, then that's how you do it. and @JackLawrence, u're right, swift currently doesn't support it

Comment: @ChrisR I'm using preprocessor macros which basically mean the code IS reachable but the compiler thinks it isn't. The warning is frustrating in this scenario. I wouldn't want to suppress all occurrences of it, just a single one.